# SSRS - Need to add 3S values to report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a multiple pages SSRS report on specific data measures.

I need to add Avg, STDEV and 3S calculations on these data to the individual pages and display them in a table format or textbox on the page.

I have created a stored procedure to return a dataset with the values and the SP runs properly; I added a second dataset to the report based on the results from the SP. I can't seem to find a way to place these values on the report.

Is there a way, documentation, suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: are you just trying to display the value inside the tablix (with another dataset) or are you wanting to match it to another dataset value and then display the values?

Comment: I have created a SP that returns the 3S calculation for the values in the first dataset and want to place them on the report page in a textbox or similar.
This SP uses the same parameters as the first one
I guess you could say I'm just trying to display the values

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your dataset that contains the 3S calculation is called 3scalculation. 
Assuming it only ever returns 3 values in a single row.. Avg, STDEV and 3S

if you want to display this on your report.. you can either simply create a text box and set the expression to the following

```
= First(Fields!avg.value, "3scalculation")
```

You can do the same for others.. and you can place them in a tablix on your report as well using the same expression.. you can use.. first.. max.. min.. sum..whatever you want.. but it has to be an aggregations of some sort.

Comment: Tried to do as you said and ran into an issue of a missing datasource.
By editing code behind, I was able to add the datasource and the second dataset.  Running in debug mode I can see the values retyrieved.  I have not yet added them to the report, I've been just trying to make sure the original report would run before adding the fields for the values I want.
Now I get an error:
Unable to connect to the remote server
 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:80
I had no dataset but had a connection, now I have a dataset but no connection.
Ideas?

Comment: So I added the datasource ad the dataset in the code behind my page.  Ran it and my dataset contained the correct dat.  Now when I tried to add the dataset to the report in the design view, I cannot see it in te list of available dataset.  How can I add the dataset?  I'm inside VS2012 and don't see anywhere an option to add a dataset  and if I try to add a dataset starting in the data_sources I don't see the name of the ds I created inn the code, anywhere (and obviously the selection is only between a few selections)